# std::set iterating over all pairs

Tags: c++, stl, stdset

Consider `code snippet 1`:

```
#include <set>
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    std::set<int> intset = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    for(std::set<int>::iterator it1 = intset.begin(); it1 != intset.end(); it1++)
      for(std::set<int>::iterator it2 = it1 + 1; it2 != intset.end(); it2++)
            printf("Pair {%d,%d}\n", *it1, *it2);
}
```

This does not compile. See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/G3veEoYjv).

Yet, I am not able to see how this way of iterating over all pairs is any different from [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1824900/492307) to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824838/iterating-over-all-pairs-of-elements-in-std-containers-c).

Paraphrasing from the accepted answer there, consider `code snippet 2`:

```
for (auto it1 = intset.begin(); it1 != intset.end(); ++it1) {
  for (auto it2 = it1; ++it2 != intset.end(); /**/) {
     printf("Pair {%d,%d}\n", *it1, *it2);
  }
}
```

I have verified that this above code indeed works fine. Yet, what is the underlying reason that the `code snippet 1` does not compile, while `code snippet 2` above does?

In both cases, are we not just incrementing a set iterator? In one case, we are doing `it2 = it1 + 1`, while in the other, we are doing `++it2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`it1 + 1` is a random access operation, so it requires the iterator to be a random access iterator, and since `std::set<int>::iterator` is not a random access iterator, it does not support this operation.

`++it2` requires that the iterator is a forward iterator, and since `std::set<int>::iterator` is a bidirectional iterator, it is a forward iterator.